# Displaying the settings/EULA and config once only for the Android app depending on the language settings

Tags: android, localization, eula

I have a quick question implementing EULA for Android depending the lanuguage selection. Assume the following scenario:

1) user selects the language may be using the language spinner
 2) Depending on the language selection, display the EULA in that specific language
 3) after this display preferences/settings
 4) After the above three steps start the actual app activity
 5) First three steps should be displayed only once during the first install

After the first install, for subsequent usage first three steps above should not be displayed.

Question is

1) Is it good to have two apks and then use the installer to install the setup apk once only and for subsequent runs start the second apk directly.

2) is it good to have only one apk and then have the mechanism to suppress the setup part after subesquent installs.

is there are any open source projects for multilingual EULA please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can save the language setting as a preference and read it when the user starts the application the second (third, etc) time. Then the activity can either load the language spinner and EULA (if first time) or proceed normally (if subsequent time).

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or a [Preference Obfuscator (such as AESObfuscator)](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#impl-Obfuscator) from the [License Verification library (LVL)](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html)